# Add Bearer token to Burp-request programatically when "401 Unauthorized" occurs

Tags: oauth-2.0, bearer-token, burp

I'm testing a application that uses `OAuth2` with bearer tokens to authorize requests. The problem I'm having is that the access token expires after 600 seconds (10 minutes) and then all requests become `401 Unauthorized`. The problem occurring now is that the scanner can continue to run with a bad token and not refresh the token automatically.

What I would like to do in this case is that the application automatically logs back in.

What I have tried is to go to `Project options` -> `Session handling rules` -> `Add` -> `Rule Actions` -> `Check session is valid` with options `Issue current request`. While there I check the response body for "Authorization denied" which is always sent on a HTTP 401. After this happens I have a macro that issues a request to get me a new access token. However I need to map the new access token to the `Authorization: Bearer`-header. Has anyone done this? It can be easily done with cookies from this view but I can't find how to do it with tokens.

Using `Burp Suite Professional v1.7.14`

Answer (score 0):

Since burp doesn't treat (non-cookie) headers as session identifiers, it's difficult to do this within Burp Suite, although you may be able to use macros, those fire every request and are very inefficient.

I recommend using this burp extension, which is designed to solves this problem: https://github.com/alexlauerman/UpdateToken